# What am I missing in this limit question

Tags: limits

Given that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{x^2+ax+b}{x+1} = 2b
$$

Determine $a+b$.

All I could think of was applying L'Hospital's Rule:

$$
\lim_{x \to -1} 2x+a = 2b \implies a-2=2b.
$$

Where do I go from there?

Comment: Try doing the division directly and determine under what circumstances the limit can exist?

Comment: The numerator has to vanish for $x=-1$.

Comment: @rolandcyp But if $g(x)\to 0$ and $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} \to K$ where $K$ is not infinite or otherwise indeterminate, it will not be possible for $f(x) \not \to 0$.  So we can apply L'hopital.  But I think we had to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ Use the fact that $1-a+b=0.$

Comment: We only know that if we assume $(-1)^2 + (-1)a + b = 0$.  Can we make that assumption?

Comment: @fleablood if the numerator doesn't contain the factor $x+1$ then the limit would be unbounded.

Comment: That was my point.  We have to note that.

Comment: Yeah that's quite clear though @fleablood.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K= \lim_{x\to -1} x^2 + ax + b = (-1)^2 +a(-1) + b = 1 - a + b$.

$\lim_{x\to -1} x+1 = (-1)+1 = 0$

We are told that $\lim_{x\to -1}\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1} = 2b$.

If $K \ne 0$ then we can assume that:

$\frac {2b}{K} = \frac {\lim_{x\to -1} \frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1}}{\lim_{x\to -1} x^2 +ax + b} = \lim_{x\to -1}\frac {\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1}}{x^2 + ax + b} = \lim_{x\to -1}\frac 1{x+1}$.  But that's a contradiction as we know $\lim_{x\to -1^+} \frac 1{x+1} = \infty$ and  $\lim_{x\to -1^-} \frac 1{x+1} = -\infty$.

So $K=1 -a + b = 0$ and $\frac {x^2 + ax +b}{x+1}|_{x=-1}$ is in indeterminate $\frac 00$ form.  So we can use L'hopital.

NOTE:  It's actually important that we determine that using L'hopital is *VALID* before we assume we can.  But if $\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x + 1}$ *weren't* in indeterminate from we'd have an unbounded limit.  But we *HAD* to determine that.  You took it for granted.

You determined that if we use L'hopital we get $2-a = 2b$.

But you overlooked the for us to be able to use l'hopital in the first place we must have $1-a+b = 0$.

So we have:

$1-a+b =0$ and

$2-a = 2b$

Solve.

===== old answer =====

we can only apply L'hopital if $\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1}$ is in indeterminate form for $x = -1$.  As $x+1 = 0$ if $x =-1$ for $\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1}$ to be in indeterminate form we must have $x^2 + ax + b=0$ for $x=-1$.

But if we *DON'T* have that we *CAN'T* assume we may use L'hopital.

However if $x^2 + ax + b=K \ne 0$ for $x = -1$ then we have a case where $\lim_{x\to -1} x^2 + ax + b = K \ne 0$ and $\lim_{x\to -1}\frac {x^2 + ax + b}{x+1} = 2b$ so therefore $\lim_{x\to -1} \frac 1{x+1}=\lim_{x\to -1} \frac {x^2+ax + b}{x+1}*\frac 1{x^2 +ax + b} = \frac {2b}{K}$.  But we know that is impossible as $\lim_{x\to -1} \frac 1{x+1}$ does not converge.

So $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ for $x = -1$.  And so $1 - a + b =0$.

And we *can* use L'Hopital  $\lim_{x\to -1} \frac {2x + a}{1}=2(-1) + a = 2b$

So we have $1-a + b =0$ and $-2+a = 2b$.

Solve.

So

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\dfrac{x^2+ax+b}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to -1}\dfrac{2x+a}{1}\to a-2$$

Notice that since we applied L'Hopital's rule, we must be careful of satisfying the condition under which L'Hopital's rule can be applied. Notice that both functions in the numerator and the denominator are continuous, so continuity is not a problem, we have to make sure that $\lim_{x\to -1}x^2+ax+b$ must also go to $0$ as the denominator goes to $0$. Since we know that $a-2=2b$ and $x^2+ax+b\to 0$ as $x\to -1$.

$$\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}a-2&=2b\\ 1-a+b&=0\end{aligned}\end{cases}\implies \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix}\implies a+b=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}$ always try to substitute $x=x_0+u$ with $u\to 0$.

Expansions in zero, and consequently limits are always easier to manipulate.

So lets calculate $f(u-1)=\dfrac{(u-1)^2+a(u-1)+b}u=\underbrace{u}_{\to 0}+(a-2)+(1+b-a)\underbrace{\dfrac 1u}_{\to\infty}$

Since the exercise stipulate that it has a finite limit $2b$ then the term in $\frac 1u$ must vanish: $1+b-a=0$

The limit is now $(a-2)$ which also equal $2b$.

Thus solve the system

$\begin{cases} 1+b-a=0\\a-2=2b\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a=b+1\\b+1-2=2b\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a=0\\b=-1\end{cases}$

And you can verifiy that $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x+1}=x-1\to -2=2b$